# Ubuntu Server 20.04 RAID 5 disk space

Tags: 20.04, raid

I have installed Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 on a HP Rack server with Raid 5.
The hardware raid pgm indicates 1.1tb of space.
Ubuntu DF command reports only 98gb.

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              3.2G   11M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G   98G     0 100% /
tmpfs                               16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                               16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2128
/dev/loop1                          33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12704
/dev/loop2                          71M   71M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21029
/dev/sda2                          976M  207M  703M  23% /boot
/dev/loop3                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2284
/dev/loop4                          44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14549
/dev/loop5                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1328
/dev/loop6                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21835
tmpfs                              3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1000
```

`lsblk` reports:

```
sda                         8:0    0  1.7T  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0  1.7T  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  100G  0 lvm  /
```

`df -h` reports:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G   37G   57G  40% /
```

---

Sorry about typo. Its RAID 0  Logical Drive = (4x300gb drives).
Raid utility reported: 1.1TB

I install Ubuntu 20.40 server and its DF reports only 98gb if space,

*** Thanks all. I resolved the problem by re-installing Ubuntu 20.04 server and unchecking LVM. I didn't realize that LVM and Hardware Raid were related. ***

Comment: Add the output from `sudo parted -lm` to your question. The partition table information is missing. Also the output of `sudo lsblk` would be use full.

Comment: I'm a bit confused why you would implement LVM on top of Raid 5.

Comment: Use **edits** to add information to your question, this is not a forum where you do reply after reply to the answer section.

Comment: @user535733 if RAID5 is done by the hardware then Ubuntu won't notice it.  Most HP Racks run RAID cards.  the LVM portion is a 'defaults selected' Ubuntu setup - you have to manually deselect LVM to make it not use it.

Comment: The problem here is the LVM volume has not been expanded to fill the disk.  This is why you're only seeing 98GB - the logical volume inside LVM is not expanded to the full spaces, and requires some work to get it to be filled.  Right now i'm on my phone so i can't send you the instructions, if nobody else has I'll give you instructions in the morning (unless someone beats me to it)